# Parenting with orientation constraint for the game engine

Tags: game-engine, constraints, parent

I am trying to set a lamp in my scene so that it will follow the player wherever he goes yet still maintains its orientation. if I parent it to the player object, when I rotate the cube, the lamp will rotate also due to its initial orientation and it messes up the lightning. Is there a proper way through this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vertex Parenting to a single vertex.

- Select child <kbd>right mouse button</kbd>
- Add parent to selection <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right mouse button</kbd>
- Switch to edit mode <kbd>tab</kbd>
- Select a single vertex from mesh <kbd>right mouse button</kbd>
- Establish vertex parent <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Leave edit mode <kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why it worked this way ?

Comment: A vertex has no orientation ... therefore the child can't inherit it.